# Grunt SCSS - Not reloading

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to achieve a smooth workflow.

my problem:

My JS modifications are shown and minified and the live reload works fine. When I make changes to my SCSS files they do not run under the run command:

```
grunt
```

or the grunt plugin:

```
grunt watch
```

It only works when I invoke:

```
grunt sass
```

This was the output from the 'grunt sass' console window:

```
Macintosh:grunt-test Neil$ grunt sass
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
File "css/global.css" created.

Done, without errors.
```

Notes:

When I run 'grunt watch' on a sass file I have noticed that grunt runs the minification on the javascript for no reason. Surely this be invoked when that file or one of its dependencies is effected?

Gruntfile.js Contents:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// 1. All configuration goes here 
grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    watch: {
        options: {
            files: ['css/*.css'],
            livereload: true
        },

        css: {
            files: ['css/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            }
        },

        scripts: {
            files: ['js/*.js', 'scss/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            }
        }
    },

    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },

            expand: true,
            cwd: 'scss/',
            src: ['*.scss'],
            dest: 'css/',
            ext: '.css'
        }
    },

    concat: {
        // 2. Configuration for concatinating files goes here.

        dist: {
            src: [
                'js/libs/*.js', // All JS in the libs folder
                'js/global.js'  // This specific file
            ],
            dest: 'js/build/production.js',
        }
    },

    uglify: {
        build: {
            src: 'js/build/production.js',
            dest: 'js/build/production.min.js'
        }
    },

    imagemin: {
        dynamic: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'images-lossy/',
                src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                dest: 'images/'
            }]
        },

        png: {
            options: {
                optimizationLevel: 7
            }
        },

        jpg: {
            options: {
                progressive: true
            }
        }
    }
});

// 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.

// CONCATENATION PLUGIN
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
// MINIFY PLUGIN
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
// IMG CRUSH PLUGIN
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
// GRUNT WATCH PLUGIN
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
// SASS LIBARY PLUGIN
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

// 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass','concat', 'uglify', 'imagemin', 'watch']);

};
```

I hope the above information helps. I have previously used Codekit, and it a really great app. I want to move to grunt but maybe my configuration file is incorrect I am close.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

- Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both of your issues occur within the `watch` configuration.

First, the reason the SASS task isn't working during watch is due to the `files` entry pointing to the wrong location. Your current files entry points to the "css" folder, but it should point to the "scss" folder, according to what you've specified in the actual "sass" task. In other words, your entry should be: `files: ['scss/*.scss']`.

```
css: {
  files: ['scss/*.scss'],
  tasks: ['sass'],
  options: {
    spawn: false,
  }
}
```

Second, the JavaScript minification occurs during the watch whenever a SASS file changes because you have it listed here:

```
scripts: {
  files: ['js/*.js', 'scss/*.scss'], // <-- scss is covered here
  tasks: ['concat', 'uglify'],
  options: {
    spawn: false,
  }
}
```

Change it to `files: ['js/*.js'],` instead to have the watch task kick in for JavaScript files only.

Once you address those issues, if things are slightly working you might want to expand the patterns so that it covers all files in the subdirectories for your JavaScript, CSS, SASS, etc. For example, `js/*.js` includes all `.js` files under the `js` folder, while `js/**/*.js` covers the `js` folder and its subfolders. You can read more under the GruntJS ["globbing patterns"](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) documentation.

EDIT: here's how the updated `watch` should look like...

```
watch: {
    options: {
        livereload: true
    },

    // css is really for Sass
    css: {
        files: ['scss/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        }
    },
    // scripts will detect js changes
    scripts: {
        files: ['js/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        }
    }
},
```

As mentioned, your individual tasks might need to use the `**` pattern similar to what I've done with the "scripts" entry above: `js/**/*.js`

Comment: Thanks, it works great now. I am presuming that if I put jshint in the task. It will only run on the js or will it apply to anything in the files: [...] ?

Comment: @Neil if you place it in the `scripts` tasks it will be triggered by js changes. Now what it applies to is determined by how you've setup the jshint task outside of watch, typically the same js files excluding your third party libraries like jQuery, etc. I imagine you would have `tasks: ['jshint','concat', 'uglify']`

Comment: So if I wanted to focus on the SCSS and stop grunt from loading JS (tasks above) what would I do. I don't see why I should edit SCSS files and reload JS tasks from grunt. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Neil I agree that your Sass files should not participate with or trigger the JS task. I believe I covered that in my second point above where I indicated the Sass files pattern was part of the scripts files section. It shouldn't be. Did that not address your needs or am I misunderstanding your question? Scripts should only look at .js extensions and would not be impacted by Sass changes.

Comment: I can see where I am going wrong, and that the task applies to the files. That was common sense I lacked this at late night attention, ha. However I have little direction to complete this issue. Would I have to create a similar block as scripts, but call it scss and mimic the properties to match?

Comment: @Neil I've updated my response with what `watch` should look like. If that's not what you're after please clarify and update your question with your current updated config (with comments) so I can understand what the issue is.

Comment: I have updated the code and it works like a dream. I now am familiar with getting the independant scripts to compile correct. I was wondering how to load compass into the gruntfile also. The installation, at the footer was easy. However it fails during config, the notes her are very weak - http://ryanchristiani.com/add-compass-to-your-grunt-task/. I have used this plugin (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass).